# How to add type to passed arguments in typescript?

Tags: typescript

i have code like below,

```
const input = [
    {
        id: 'id',
        name: 'description',
        customCell: (_:any, {message, info}) => //error here message and info have implicity               any
            message? message : info,
    },
]
```

how to add type to message and info in customCell

i have tried like below,

```
const input = [
    {
        id: 'id',
        name: 'description',
        customCell: (_:any, {message: any, info: any}) =>//duplicate identifier any. any is declared but its value never read
            message? message : info,
    },
]
```

but it gives error like

duplicate identifier any. any is declared but its value never read

How can i fix this. could someone help me with this.

Comment: Try `customCell: (_: any, { message, info }: { message: any; info: any }) => ...`

Comment: Yeah, there's unfortunately no shorthand for this (see [ms/TS#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526)) so the annotation will necessarily repeat the property names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
customCell: (_:any, {message: any, info: any})=>
```

Why won't you name the second parameter ?

it should be something like this.

```
customCell: (_:any, foo: {message: any, info: any})=>
```